# ng-repeat выдает пустые значения в django TemplateView

Tags: django, angularjs

например у меня есть вот такое приложение. если я просто открою страницу с ним в браузере все будет работать как надо

```html
<!doctype html>
<html  ng-app="pApp">
<body ng-controller="Test">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pApp = angular.module("pApp", []);
pApp.controller('Test', function($scope){})

</script>

</body>
```

но если я открою этот шаблон через Django TemplateView я увижу пустые значения, сами Элементы списка останутся, но в них не будет данных.
что это за баг? как его исправить?

AngularJS v1.6.4
 Django: 1.11

Comment: Django Template понимает как свои шаблоны и пытается проставить {{item}}. Вам нужен escaping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772001/how-to-escape-or-in-django-template

Comment: да точно, но блин как то в другом тестовом приложении у меня все работает. пойдму гляну может забыл что-то подгрузить

Comment: а вот оно что, там используется  stateProvider и в  templateUrl указывается модифицируемый  кусочек шаблона. так что в том случае джанга ничего не подозревала о таких переменных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что шаблонизатор Django интерпретирует значение внутри двойных скобок, как переменную контекста, не обнаруживает таковой и оставляет пустое место, а ангуляр потом с пустым местом ничего не делает. Есть два способа решения этой проблемы. Во-первых, можно в ангуляре использовать другую последовательность символов вместо двойных фигурных скобок:

```
pApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

Во-вторых, можно в шаблонах django не трогать участки разметки, относящиеся к фронту:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]">
        {{item}}
    </li>
{% endverbatim %}
```